# Finding sine of an angle in degrees without $\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, pi

The following is found using a combination of: (a) a polygon with an infinite number of sides is a circle, (b) the perimeter of that polygon is the circumference of the circle that it becomes (of course), (c) the sine theorem, and (d) the ratio between the circumference of a circle and the diameter is $\pi$. 
$$\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin \left(\frac{180}{n}\right)^o$$
I have been trying to rewrite the above expression without $sin$ in it explicitly. So, I researched other expressions for $sin$, and found this:
$$\sin (x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}-\frac{x^{11}}{11!}+\cdots$$
Attempting to rewrite this Taylor series in Sigma notation yielded this:
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}(-1)^{n-1}$$
The issue for me is that I have an angle measure in degrees, but $x$ above is in radians. I would convert the degrees to radians and be done with it just like that, except that I feel that solving for $\pi$ with $\pi$ is like defining a word with itself, and is 'cheating'.

I have been trying to find a way to make this conversion without $\pi$ but to no avail. I also tried using trig identities, but that has just led me in circles.

Is there another way to find the sine of $x^o$ without involving $\pi$ at all?

An even more explicit and blunt form of my question: What is another way to express $sin(x^o)$ without using $\pi$?

To be clear, I am not looking for anything that involves approximations or infinite series that cannot be wholly expressed in a finite amount of space (ex. Taylor series above is okay because it can be expressed in sigma notation).

Comment: How would finding the sine of an angle $x$, where $x$ is measured in degrees, help you to write an exact expression for $\pi$?

Comment: @DavidK - edited. Please tell me of I should elaborate

Comment: Sines and cosines of rational numbers of degrees can be computed as roots of polynomials, without involving $\pi$ at all.  For example, $\sin(1 \text{ degree})$ is a root of a polynomial of degree $48$ that's too big to fit in a comment.

Comment: If you want $\sin(180/n \text{ degrees})$ for $n$ a power of $2$, just repeatedly use the half-angle formulas.

Comment: (1)You cannot convert from radians to degrees or vice-versa without using $\pi$ because $180^o= \pi$ radians.   (2)  A circle is not really an infinite-sided polygon. (3)  To prove $\pi=\lim_{n\to \infty} n \sin (180/n)^o$ you need a def'n of $\pi$ to begin.  Define $\pi$ as the length of a semi-circle of radius $1$. Then you need to define what  "length  of a semi-circle"  means: It's the limit of the perimeters of polygons that uniformly approximate it  This  implies $\pi=\lim n\sin (180/n)^o.$  (4)The power series  for $\sin x $ is in radians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in a comment, there are equations you can write for the
trigonometric functions of rational portions of a right angle
(and therefore for the sine of any rational number of degrees)
without using $\pi$ or any trigonometric functions.
To actually use these equations may prove somewhat cumbersome, however.

Instead of attempting a formula for an arbitrary integer or rational
number of degrees, let me just address the desire to evaluate
$$
\newcommand{\Sin}{\mathop{\mathrm{Sin}}}
\newcommand{\Cos}{\mathop{\mathrm{Cos}}}
\lim_{n\to\infty} n \Sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)
$$
where $\Sin$ is the sine function that takes its parameter in degrees,
for example, $\Sin(90) = 1$.

It is sufficient to examine the following limit for integer values of $k$:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} 2^k \Sin\left(\frac{180}{2^k}\right).
$$
The quantity $\Sin\left(\frac{180}{2^k}\right)$ is easy to compute
(at least, it is easy compared to such values as $\Sin(1)$).
Let $\Cos(x)$ be the cosine function for $x$ measured in degrees;
then apply the half-angle formula for cosines of angles in the 
interval from $0$ to $180$ degrees, inclusive:
$$
\Cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \Cos x}{2}}.
$$

If $x = \dfrac{180}{2^m}$, then $\dfrac x2 = \dfrac{180}{2^{m+1}}$
and the half-angle formula just says that
$$
\Cos\left(\frac{180}{2^{m+1}}\right)
 = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \Cos \left(\frac{180}{2^m}\right)}{2}}.
$$

You can find the value for any $k$ by starting at $m=1$ and applying the
half-angle formula repeatedly for $m=2,3,\ldots, k$:
\begin{align}
\Cos\left(\frac{180}{2}\right) &= \Cos(90) = 0,\\
\Cos\left(\frac{180}{4}\right) &=
 \sqrt{\frac{1 + \Cos \left(\frac{180}{2}\right)}{2}}
 = \sqrt{\frac{1 + 0}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, \\
\Cos\left(\frac{180}{8}\right) &=
 \sqrt{\frac{1 + \Cos \left(\frac{180}{4}\right)}{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 2 + 1}{2\sqrt 2}}, \\
\Cos\left(\frac{180}{16}\right) &=
 \sqrt{\frac{1 + \Cos \left(\frac{180}{8}\right)}{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt 2 + 1}{2\sqrt 2}}}{2}}
= \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt 2} + \sqrt{\sqrt 2 + 1}}{2\sqrt{2\sqrt 2}}}, \\
\end{align}
and so forth to obtain $\Cos\left(\frac{180}{2^k}\right)$
for $k$ as large as desired.
Then obtain the sine by
$$
\Sin\left(\frac{180}{2^k}\right) =
\sqrt{1 - \left(\Cos\left(\frac{180}{2^k}\right)\right)^2}.
$$

Comment: How would I calculate $Cos(\frac{180}{2^k})$ with a degree measure, then? Wouldn't that involve yet another Taylor series that takes radians and not degrees? (From looking at this page: http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf)

Comment: No, you do not need to use Taylor series. I have shown all the calculations explicitly for $k = 1,2,3,4$. Just continue like that for higher powers of $2$. You _do_ have to take a square root each time.

Comment: Do I not need to somehow calculate $Cos(\frac{180}{2^k})$, though? How would I calculate that?

Comment: I have given step-by-step instructions. First compute $\newcommand{\Cos}{\mathop{\mathrm{Cos}}}\Cos(180/2)$, then $\Cos(180/4)$, then $\Cos(180/8)$, and so forth using the half-angle formula exactly as shown. The denominator doubles each time, so if you do this enough times the denominator will be $2^k$.

Comment: How do we know that these formulas use degrees and not radians?

Answer (score 0):

In relation to David K's answer, I also note one small problem:

$$\sin(\frac x2)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}2}$$

Obviously, $\sin(\frac x2)$ being negative is fully possible.

However, we know that for $0\le x\le\pi$, $\sin(x)>0$, in other words, it is positive.

On the interval from $-\frac{\pi}2\le x\le\frac{\pi}2$, $\cos(x)>0$.

So, we may start with $\cos(1)\approx0.540302306$.

We have $$\cos(0.5)\approx0.877581562$$

$$\cos(0.25)\approx0.968912422$$

$$\cos(0.125)\approx0.992197667$$

etc. (these values were obtained through the half angle formula)

Similarly, we have: (using half angle formula)

$$\sin(1)\approx0.841470985$$

$$\sin(0.5)\approx0.479425539$$

$$\sin(0.25)\approx0.247403959$$

$$\sin(0.125)\approx0.124674733$$

etc.

Now, knowing our trigonometric identities, one can use the sum of angles formula to approximate the desired value to desired accuracy.